# How to create elements that fill the line evenly to the end, like on img below?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wonder what is the best way to do it like img. I mean block alignment
from left to right and taking the maximum length of the row.
Which is better, write a script specifying and adapting the block size to the container size, or do it somehow using the css grid. I don't want a ready solution, just tips. Regarding the code, I wrote only so much and I think how to transform it. That's why I'm looking for a hint (What I want to get https://i.ibb.co/jkgTrzT/how-to-create-a-row-of-elements-of-different-width-inside-grid.png)(what I got https://i.ibb.co/p0NkD8K/what-I-got.png)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tags">
    <a href="">food</a>
    <a href="">photography</a>
    <a href="">web design</a>
    <a href="">art</a>
    <a href="">love</a>
    <a href="">business</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tags {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.tags a {
    padding: 12px 24px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid rgba(144, 144, 144, .5);
    color: black;
    margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: .5s ease;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't add a photo otherwise because of my reputation dont be angry for that

Comment: Set up the parent as a flex container with wrapping enabled, and let the children grow as needed …?

Comment: Hey Theillo, Welcome to the stack overflow, i think you can do it by simply using `float:left` to every anchor tag.

Comment: I don't see a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to display the tags in flexbox. When the tags have `flex: 1;`, they will fill up remaining space.

```css
.tags {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tag {
    display: block;
    flex: 1;
    min-width: something;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what widths to expect in your `a` elements, you could just use `float` and `clear` styles, something like this:

```css
.tags {
  width: 270px;
  padding: 20 px 0;
}

.tags a {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid rgba(144, 144, 144, .5);
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.left { float: left;   margin: 0 15px 15px 0; }
.right { float: right;   margin: 0 15px 15px 0; }
.clear{ clear: both; }
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <div class="clear">  
    <div class="left"><a href="">food</a></div>
    <div class="right"><a href="">photography</a></div>
  </div>  
  <div class="clear">
    <div class="left"><a href="">web design</a></div>
    <div class="right"><a href="">art</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear">  
    <div class="left"><a href="">love</a></div>
    <div class="right"><a href="">business</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```